# how to force pull data at 1st registration in symmetricds

Tags: android, symmetricds

I created android symmetricds client. After register process, I don't see any data pulled by symmetricds client. The data will push by server or pull by client after I modified data in server. I'm using postgresql. What I want to do, client register, show the message that data still pulling from server. After data populated in sqlite, hide the message and android client ready to use. Any info would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add this entry in the symmetric-ds.properties file on the server:

```
auto.reload=true
```

it will cause every client to automatically retrieve the initial load after registering.

On the client poll this query

```
select count(*)
from   sym_incoming_batch sib
where  sib.status != 'OK';
```

Once it dropped to 0 the initial load has successfully been retrieved.